# How to set console encoding in MSYS?

Tags: console, msys

I'm using MSYS in windows environment (not my choice), and some of my files are inside folders with names in a different encoding than that of the MSYS console.

So, how can I change the encoding used by the MSYS shell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click on menu bar, choose "Options..."

[image]

In the "Text" section, select your encoding.

[image]